# How to locate the link of the tag I want from a tags with the same class with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to go to the jobs section on LinkedIn with selenium, but it leads to the connections(networks) section with the same class name. how do i solve this problem?

[image]

My code;

```
jobs_sec = driver.find_element("xpath", "//a[@class='app-aware-link global-nav__primary-link']")
jobs_sec.click()
```

The tag reached when run;
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.app-aware-link.global-nav__primary-link[href^='https://www.linkedin.com/jobs']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='app-aware-link global-nav__primary-link' and starts-with(@href, 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jobs_sec = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".app-aware-link.global-nav__primary-link")))
jobs_sec.click()
```

If that doesn't work, try as an alternative:

```
jobs_sec = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-nnt-old-href='https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/?']")))
jobs_sec.click()
```

You will also need to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't

Comment: I added an alternative, try it as well